# default /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.backupd-auto.plist file

Tags: macos, time-machine

I have messed up my time machine backup file and did not back it up.

Can anybody please post the default file from:

```
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.backupd-auto.plist
```

for El Capitan (10.11.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>MachServices</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.backupd-helper.status</key>
        <dict>
            <key>HideUntilCheckIn</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>com.apple.backupd-auto</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.backup.launcher</string>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.apple.backupd-auto</string>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/Resources/backupd-helper</string>
        <string>-launchd</string>
    </array>
    <key>LaunchEvents</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.xpc.activity</key>
        <dict>
            <key>com.apple.backupd-auto</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Interval</key>
                <integer>3600</integer>
                <key>Delay</key>
                <integer>3600</integer>
                <key>GracePeriod</key>
                <integer>1800</integer>
                <key>Repeating</key>
                <true/>
                <key>AllowBattery</key>
                <true/>
                <key>PowerNap</key>
                <true/>
                <key>Priority</key>
                <string>Utility</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>EnableTransactions</key>
    <true/>
    <key>POSIXSpawnType</key>
    <string>Background</string>
    <key>EnablePressuredExit</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```